# Sending text message from one iPhone device to another using NSNetServices

Tags: iphone, sms, nsnetservice

I want to send the text message from one iPhone device to another iphone device or simulator    using NSNetServices. Can anyone has idea how to figure out this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to connect the devices with the Bluetooth Service in the GameKit Framework 
[GameKit Framework](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/GameKit_Guide/GameKitConcepts/GameKitConcepts.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008304-CH100-SW1)

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, my understanding is that you cannot send send or recieve SMS (txt messages) via the simulator.

Without further details regarding your specific problem, I'm sorry to say I can't provide a suitable alternative...

Comment: currently i have fetched all the system  connecting through same network with my system.if my application run on both system i want to send some text msg (like chatting) to another system. suppose if i am sending some text via text field in app then it will show an alert msg with that text in another system.